# Is any method in crystal report to display total price in french word

Tags: crystal-reports

ToWord function in (Crystal Report) Show Total with English word
I want to show price like exemple
120 euro => cent vingt euro
not like in english
and thanks all

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create the ToFrenchWords() logic in a Crystal formula or in a UFL (User Function Library). A list of 3rd-party UFLs is available [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl). But I'm not aware of such a function in those UFLs.

Another option is to use a general-purpose translate function from a UFL as shown in the image below. This is using one of the UFLs in the list mentioned above.
[image]

Comment: But This Solution Need Connexion Internet?

Comment: The first option doesn't need connection to the internet.

The 2nd option, if the UFL relies on Google Translate, then you need internet connection for text the UFL hasn't seen before (prior translations are stored and used locally).

Comment: Thanks very match for your reply

Comment: can you give me tutorial or explain about this 1 er solutionOne option is to create the ToFrenchWords() logic in a Crystal formula or in a UFL (User Function Library). A list of 3rd-party UFLs is available here. But I'm not aware of such a function in those UFLs.